# Reusable jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net

I am using `ASP.NET 3.5` with `C# 2008`.

I want to use a `JQuery` dialog for showing error message.

For this I need to include a CSS, a JavaScript file into aspx page. Also have to create a `<div>` with specific Id or class and have to put some buttons like OK, Cancel inside it. Also have to put a `label` inside `<div>`. And have to create a `<script>` block which contains functions to Open or Close the dialog.

All this working fine in single aspx page. But now I want to use this across all the pages and also don't want to make repetitive codes.

So what will be the best way to implement it? Should I put all these stuff inside a user-control and import it into every aspx page where I want to use that dialog? Or any other best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your javascript code into a js file and add the reference of that js file into your master page then you can call the jquery error dialog into your application.

Comment: Ya but in that case I need to put the <div> in all of the pages which has not master page. What I want to achieve is include just a single file that contains javascript, aspx <div> and function that invokes jquery dialog.

Comment: Then you need to just add the reference of your javascript file on each of the page...